# How to make Nicedit only affect one textarea on a page as oposed to every textarea on the page

Tags: javascript, textarea, nicedit

I've been trying to use nicedit (http://nicedit.com/) on a form for my website (which I am using to submit short stories).  The form includes several textareas ().  One of them is for the content of the short story, which i want to use nicedit on.  The other text area is for tags, which i do not want to use nicedit on.  However, nicedit gets applied to both.

This is the javascript code i am using to call up the nicedit code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/rte.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
//]]>
```

I checked in the nicEdit.js and the allTextAreas() corresponds to this:

```
allTextAreas : function(nicOptions) {
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++) {
nicEditors.editors.push(new nicEditor(nicOptions).panelInstance(textareas[i]));
}
return nicEditors.editors;
},
```

I also investigated on the ingetnet and could find no answer as to how to make only one text area be affected by the nicedit code.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From looking at the code you posted, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/rte.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    nicEditors.editors.push(
        new nicEditor().panelInstance(
            document.getElementById('myNicEditor')
        )
    );
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Just give your textarea whichever id you use:

```
<textarea id="myNicEditor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! I worked perfectly!  I would vote for your answer, but i don't have enough reputation :P

Comment: I'm trying to take this one step further and make it apply to a dynamic ID.

Comment: @Nathan Wall How to remove ALL instances at once?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's looking to do this with multiple textarea's by class name I'm using [Nathan Wall's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992060/1500195) with a few changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName("nice-edit");
    for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; ++i) {
      nicEditors.editors.push(
        new nicEditor().panelInstance(
          elementArray[i]
        )
      );
    }
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

Use as many text areas as you'd like with the class name `nice-edit`:

```
<textarea class="nice-edit"></textarea>
```

In Rails I use CoffeeScript and this is my modified code:

```
$ ->
  #<![CDATA[
  elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName("nice-edit")
  i = 0
  while i < elementArray.length
    nicEditors.editors.push new nicEditor(fullPanel: true).panelInstance(elementArray[i])
    ++i
  #]]>
```

You'll notice I completely removed the `bkLib.onDomLoaded` line and just called the equivelant of document function do `$ ->`.  The reason is `bkLib.onDomLoaded` fails to load initially because of **turbolinks**.  It only works with a refresh.  Thus why I've removed it.

Comment: Exactly what i want :) tnx

Answer (score 1):

I made it for all textareas by tagname using the original function as start point

```
<script type="text/javascript">

bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {

    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

    for(var i=0;i<textareas.length;i++)
     {
        var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
        myNicEditor.panelInstance(textareas[i]);

     }
});
```